# How do I install driver for rtl88x2bu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek

I have moved house and in my new house my desk, with the computer, is isolated and cannot get the cable fron the router though there is not a big distance, probably 10 meters.

So I dusted off an old dongle I bought for my laptop some time ago, I connected to a free usb 2.0 and everything went smooth I was connected to my wifi in no time, but the max I could get was 5.7 mbps Download and 7.7 upload, this with a 100 mb connection.

I tried a series of ways to get that improved with no success, so finally I decided to buy something to get this improved, first I bought a repeater, but the improve, if any, was neglectable,finally checking in different places I decided to buy a new dongle in Amazon. A wifi adaptor ac1200 with Realtek 8812Au.

It wasn't easy to make it work, my knowledge of Ubuntu is not up to a pro, but finally, following the explanations from a web site (the disk that accompanied the adapter was ALL in chinese!!):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

It started working right away giving me almost 100 mb, so I was super happy.

After 3 weeks, the adapter didn't start. I have to say the adapter must be connected to a usb 3 and as soon as it is connected there is alight that comes on, well this time not even the light was coming on.

I tried different things:

- Change the cable to another usb 3 socket, NO SUCCESS
- Change the usb 3 cable, NO SUCCESS
- Connect a external drive to the same socket with the same cable,the hdd was working
- Re-start the computer and try everything again, the same results as before.

So finally I thought that the adapter just had died, as I was still in 30 days Amazon gives you to return the goods, I returned it and, after thinking for a couple of days, I decided to buy it again.

It arrived yesterday, this time the software in the disk was in English, but I thought it would work because the driver was installed, so I plugged it in and ....Oh, surprise!! the light didn't come on, so it doesn't work.
I have been reading about this driver and installation in ubuntu this last 48 hours, but most of the places explain what I already did and, to be honest, many of then explain things I don't understand and I am afraid that if it doesn't work I will not be able to undo what I did.

Probably I should delete the driver and do everything again, but I don't know how to do it, or even if that will work.

Any help will be welcome and please, think that I am not a pro with Ubuntu, so make it easy to understand.

Right know I came back to my old dongle with 5.7 mbps right now and if I do a "lsusb" this is what I get:

```
juan@juan-desktop:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 145f:013f Trust Megapixel Auto Focus Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:0102 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse Combo [MK1152WC]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel:
juan@juan-desktop:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux$ uname -r
4.13.0-37-generic
```

The file in the small cd with the adapter has a zip file called:

```
RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719_COEX20170518-4444.20170613.20170427_TV_ANDROID_6.x_COEX_8822BS-C4242_8822BU-C4242(r1)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to reinstall the drivers whenever there's a kernel update.

Comment: do I have to uninstall the "old driver"?

Comment: In fact, your 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. is an rtl8822bu device, not rtl8812au. I suggest that you edit your question title and try to compile the driver on the CD. If it fails, we'll be happy to assist. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I copied the content of the cd onto my personal folder and opened a terminal in the "Driver" folder, make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/build M=/home/juan/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719_COEX20170518-4444.20170613.20170427_TV_ANDROID_6.x_COEX_8822BS-C4242_8822BU-C4242(r1)/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719_COEX20170518-4444.20170613/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719.20170613_COEX20170518-4444  modules
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:1794: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'modules'
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: chili555 - Sorry, I have been away for a few days, but still fighting with the adapter to make it work. I have updated the kernel to 4.16.1, and still the same. Tried with kernel 4.13, but no way. I am desperated to make it work.

Answer (score 19):

[Randy Ciwyll’s repository](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959) has the solution that worked for my system (Linux Mint 18.3 Kernel 4.10). As chili555 guessed, my device is the rtl8822bu. And yes, I have found that I need to reinstall the driver every time I get an applicable update.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms bc git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms add ./rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.3.1
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: can you explain the solution by editing your answer (detailled what works in your link) and NB : we are Ubuntu, not Mint ;)

Comment: Thanks! This worked to me for Ubuntu 18

Comment: Works after Hibernation under Mint 19.2! Anyway to use DKMS to auto configure every kernel update?

Comment: Also survives kernel updates!!!

Comment: For Ubuntu 19.10 (5.3.0 kernel), I had to use the newer https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu as these instructions were failing. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: I succeeded to follow all commands until 'sudo modprobe 88x2bu'. How come? It shows:
"modprobe: FATAL: Module 88x2bu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+

Answer (score 6):

First, install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Next, git clone and install the driver:

```
sudo git clone "https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git" /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git
sudo sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION="@PKGVER@"/PACKAGE_VERSION="git"/g' /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git/dkms.conf
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v git
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

Save any unsaved work and then reboot.

After you log back in, run the following command if it shows "no wifi adapter found".

```
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: According to the github page, you probably have to use a USB 2.0 port. [See here for more information.](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver#user-content-usb-30-support).

Comment: This worked for me. I have Ubuntu Studio 21.04, I had upgraded my internet speed from 50Mb/sec to 100Mb/sec but was only getting 25Mb/sec on my old wireless as it has an old USB wifi adaptor. So I purchased a Simplecom NW621 AC 200 wifi Adaptor with a 5dBi antenna, which should support 5/2.4 GHz dual band. The wifi adaptor came with linux (and windows and Mac) drivers, but the linux driver installation failed and gave errors. I tried @mchid's answer and everything worked perfectly. A speedtest shows a wifi speed close to 100Mb/sec.

Comment: @StuartAnderson And because the installation uses DKMS, the drivers should automatically update whenever a new kernel is installed so it saves a lot of time and headache in the future.

Comment: @mchid `git clone` says : `fatal: could not create work tree dir '/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git': Permission denied`. I guess a `sudo` is needed in front of your `git clone` command for it to be able to write into `/usr/src/`.

Comment: @SebMa Yeah I guess `sudo` is necessary. This is an unusual way to clone. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: How can I remove it? `sudo apt remove modprobe` is not working

Comment: @RxT It should be something like `sudo dkms remove <module name>/<module version> --all` so `sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/git --all` or `sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v git --all` to uninstall the dkms module for all kernels that the module is installed on for your system.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

Current Driver Version: 5.8.7.2
Support Kernel: 2.6.24 ~ 5.8 (with unofficial patches) in this case xanmod 5.8.11

1. Clone or Download: https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git
2. Navigate to the downloaded Directory (RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) & open in terminal
3. Compile (build), install & run: with the directory open in terminal, type:

   `make`                   (to compile the installer)
   `sudo make install`      (to install it)
   `sudo modprobe 88x2bu`   (to start the driver)

Supported Devices

```
ASUS AC1300 USB-AC55 B1
ASUS U2
Dlink - DWA-181
Dlink - DWA-182
Edimax EW-7822ULC
Edimax EW-7822UTC
NetGear A6150
TP-Link Archer T3U
TP-Link Archer T3U Plus
TP-Link Archer T4U V3
TRENDnet TEW-808UBM
Techkey AC 1200Mbps dual Antenna
```

And more.

more answers on the .git page.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove your current module with:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8812au
```

And then install the provided in the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Comment: How is `rtl8812au-dkms` related?