# USB Wifi Adapter FayTun stopped working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

my wifi adapter somehow stopped working (together with my graphics card) on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. After reinstalling my Nvidia driver my graphics are working again, thats not a problem. But somehow I can't get the USB adapter working again.

Outpu of lshw:

```
 *-usb UNCLAIMED                                                                                                                      
      description: Generic USB device                                                                                                 
      product: 802.11ac NIC                                                                                                           
      vendor: Realtek                                                                                                                 
      physical id: 3                                                                                                                  
      bus info: usb@3:b.3                                                                                                             
      version: 2.10                                                                                                                   
      serial: 123456                                                                                                                  
      capabilities: usb-2.10                                                                                                          
      configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

In `lsusb` the wifi adapter shows like that:

```
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

- I tried installing the drivers from this repo: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new -> No success
- I followed this article which helped in the first setup https://rehmann.co/blog/drivers-wifi-usb-adapter-osxmac-linux-windows/ -> No success
- I followed these steps, didn't work as well: [How do I install driver for rtl88x2bu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018375/how-do-i-install-driver-for-rtl88x2bu)
- Tried different USB ports without success either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install driver for rtl88x2bu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018375/how-do-i-install-driver-for-rtl88x2bu)

Comment: Unfortunately not because I already followed these steps and after `dkms add` I just get the message that it is already installed