# Install a Wireless USB adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, realtek-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I am trying to install for the first time a driver for a new Realtek USB wireless Adapter RTL88x2B. Is there a simple way to do this?

Obviously Ubuntu recognizes the hardware (see result of `lsusb` command):

```
"Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]"
```

Here is the output of the `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching HubBus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0846:9030 NetGear, Inc. WNA1100 Wireless-N 150 [Atheros AR9271]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04b4:0033 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Mouse
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1395:0025 Sennheiser Communications Headset [PC 8]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I found an answer that almost solved my issue,
[How do I install driver for rtl88x2bu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018375/how-do-i-install-driver-for-rtl88x2bu), but in the end I get an error:

```
$ sudo modprobe 88x2bu
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '88x2bu': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I installed the latest Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.